# Laplace Transformation of derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I want to rules behind the step(with arrow). I cant get how that transformation happened.

[image: enter image description]

Comment: There is just one integration by parts that you need to apply.

Comment: @Tucker: The OP lacks your skill with $\LaTeX$ and `MathJax`, so perhaps you could help them with the [introduction to posting math expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\mathcal{L}\left[y'(t)\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}y'(t)e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t
$$

$$
\mathrm{d}v=y'(t)\mathrm{d}t\longrightarrow v= y
$$

$$
u=e^{-st}\longrightarrow \mathrm{d}u=-se^{-st}\mathrm{d}t
$$
integrating by parts

$$
\mathcal{L}\left[y'(t)\right]=(e^{-st}y)|_{0}^{+\infty}+s\int_{0}^{\infty}y(t)e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t
$$

$$
(e^{-st}y)|_{0}^{+\infty}=-y(0)
$$

$$
\mathcal{L}\left[y(t)\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}y(t)e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t
$$

so one can then see

$$
\mathcal{L}\left[y'(t)\right]=s\mathcal{L}\left[y(t)\right]-y(0)
$$

Comment: i got the part where integration by parts is applied. I want to know how last is happened.

Comment: @sachal I do not know what you mean by "how last is happened". I am not sure what step you are confused about.

Comment: i am confused about the last step.

Comment: @sachal We showed that: $$\mathcal{L}\left[y'(t)\right]=s\color{green}{\int_{0}^{\infty}y(t)e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t}+\color{red}{(e^{-st}y)|_{0}^{+\infty}}$$ All you need to do now is substitute the two results obtained. $$\color{green}{\int_{0}^{\infty}y(t)e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t=\mathcal{L}\left[y(t)\right]}$$﻿ $$\color{red}{(e^{-st}y)|_{0}^{+\infty}=-y(0)﻿}$$

Comment: @sachal I made a substitution, as projectilemotion vividly elucidated.